# increase limit of query by given amount using php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Re-frased question do to new info**
I'm trying to show a limited set of results on a search (i.e. LIMIT 10 in query) then have a button that will load the next 10 (now LIMIT 20 in same query).

The problem is that when I press the button, it not only refreshes the the specified div - but it re-runs the doSearch at the very top of the page - and thereby resetting the LIMIT to 10...

So if I
1. load the result-page
2. comment out the doSearch at top of page
and first then...
3. click the button

It works as perscribed... it now show 20 results... and if I click again it shows 30... etc.

And if I uncomment the doSearch at the very top of page and click the button... it now shows 10 results again...

the code in question in the ajax-code is

```
var showResult = self.closest('#showResultsAll').find('[id^="showResults"]');
showResult.load(location.href + " #showResults>*", "");
```

I can't see why my code would re-run the doSearch at the top of page... but hopeully some of you wise folks can see the error of my ways and set me on the right path...

My basic setup:
page with results:

```
<?php // get search results limit 10 ?>
.
.
.
<div id="showResultsAll">
    .
    .
    .
    <div id="showResults">
        // Loop through and show results
        <div id="moreResultsButton">
            <input type="hidden" name="search" id="search" value="<?php // search terms ?>">
            <button id="moreResults" value="<?php // number of results found ?>">
```

jquery.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    $(document).on('click','button[id^="moreResults"]', function(){
        var self = $(this);
        var closestDiv = self.closest('#moreResultsButton');
        var search = closestDiv.find('[id^="search"]').val();
        var count = self.val();
        var countNew = + count + 10;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'../scripts/moreresults.php',
            data:"countNew="+countNew+"&search="+search,
            success:function(){
                var showResult = self.closest('#showResultsAll').find('[id^="showResults"]');
                showResult.load(location.href + " #showResults>*", "");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

moreresults.php

```
session_start ();

require ( "../scripts/functions.php" );

// Set variable
$search = $_POST['search'];
$limit = $_POST['countNew'];

doSearch ( $pdo , $search , $limit ); // same function that found the search results in the first place
```

**Update**
So found a solution loosely based on an answer given below by [@delCano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2984265/delcano) (although I'm still curious as to why my original code insisted on rerunning the doSearch at the top of the page)

**Solution:**
I split everything up by first dropping the limit in the doSearch and just let it find all results and then did the 'limiting' in the show-results part of the page, and then just added 10 to that in my jQuery

**New code:**
page with results

```
<?php // doSearch no limit ?>
.
.
.
<div id="showResultsAll">
    .
    .
    .
    <div id="showResults">
        // Loop through and show results - limiting like this
        // if isset $_POST['show'] (ie. button clicked)
            // if $_POST['show'] less than $_SESSION['totalResults'] (ie. more results coming)
                // $show = $_POST['show'] (ie. 20, 30, etc.)
            // else
                // $show = $_SESSION['totalResults'] (ie. 11, 12, ..., 21, 22, ..., 31, 32, ..., etc.)
        // else (if button not clicked limit results to max. 10) 
            // if $_SESSION['totalResults'] more than 10
                // $show = 10 
            // else
                // $show = $_SESSION['totalResults'] (ie. 1, 2, 3, etc.)
        // loop trough $show number of results

        <div class="<?php if $show == $_SESSION['totalResults'] echo "disabled" // Only active if more results are available ?>" id="moreResultsButton">
            <button id="moreResults" value="<?php echo $show; ?>">
```

jQuery.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    $(document).on('click','button[id^="moreResults"]', function(){
        var self = $(this);
        var show = self.val();
        var showNew = + show + 10;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'',
            data:"show="+showNew,
            success:function(){
                self.closest('#showResultsAll').find('[id^="showResults"]').load(location.href + " #showResults>*", "");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is doSearch function? Show your codes

Comment: doSaerach is in functions.php - (ie. require ("../scripts/functions.php"); called on top of page)

Comment: ps. the doSearch find the results fine... otherwise it woldn't find the 10 fist results in the first place...

Comment: declare the `countNew` outside the click.. because every time you click the button, it refreshes the value..

Comment: @ShadowFiend didn't help and if I put an alert under success with the countNew value ir shows an alert with the number 20... so the countNew passed to morereesults.php as new limit is 20 and the do search find 20 results... the problem is that nothing new is showing...

Comment: Why are you using the attribute starts with selector `id^=x` instead of just selecting directly by id with `#x`?

Comment: @nnnnnn in this particular case it makes no difference pr. se. but I prefer this selector as a general rule because it opens up for the posibility to access several id's at once as it looks for all child-objects that starts with the string and not just exactly like string as using # does (and this instance is the exception where I don't need that - because of dynamically created content using loops I 98% of the time need the dynamic id^= selector - so it just got to be a habit - but here it accomplises the same)

Comment: If you've got dynamic content created in a loop it is usually more manageable to use a common class name rather than assigning IDs and using a starts-with selector.

Comment: I would think the result would be the same between the 2 in the case you want to select several instances of the selector.... and adding an extra class to use when I already have dynamically selected id's (ie. comment0, comment1, comment2, etc) why not just use them with id^="comment" and not have to add anything...

Comment: @nnnnnn PS. I would love to have this talk about why one over the other and maybe learn something about the finer ddetails of jQuery and aljax programming... and if you want - please PM me ... but let's not have it here in the comment section... my problem still stands... I can't get my page to show the new result set... any idea why?

Comment: I don't get your `success` function. Why are you using `load` to get the data again? The return from the server via ajax should be passed onto the `success(result)` function in an argument; you should therefore be able to simply put it inside the div with a `showResult.html(result)` or something similar. Your way seems needlessly complicated, unless I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: @delCano because showResult.html(result) shows nothing... not the first 10 results not the 20 results... nothing... when I click the button... my success as it is boils down to find the parent.div to the one I want to refresh... find the child.div of that that I want to refresh... and then use load to reload that div and that div alone....

Comment: You didn't forget to add `result` to the list of arguments of the `success` function, right?

Comment: nope added it... btw... see update 2 of my post... have any idea why? there is a big bold upvote and check mark in it for you :)

Comment: Hello APM, please avoid cursing in your question. I very much do understand that programming can get frustrating, though if you need to vent check out devRant.com ;) For stackoverflow please remain calm and also ask your question to the point, this includes avoiding fuzzy languages or multiple `...`. There is no need to ask "if we can help" once nor muiltiple times; helping one another is what the platform is here for. It's also not helpful to a reader if you add your updates at the top of the question. Rather edit them right into the question or at the bottom.

Comment: I recommend checking the [how to ask a good question on so](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As a workaround, after your last reformulation, why don't you remove the inline'd `doSearch` and start everything with 0 results, then, extract all the `onclick function` to a named function, associate it with the click event and also force an execution on page load? I still think you could use ajax in a more efficient manner somehow, but this is the best I can think of without refactoring the whole thing.

Comment: @delCano I'm fairly new to ajax an jquery so please feel free to tell me how I could do it better... I'm actually very interested in learning... so if you have the time to tell me how you would accomplice the task I presented then you will have my gratitude.. if not no hard feelings... but am interested.. but to your suggestion..  how on earth would I force an onclick function without a click? and could you please tell me what it is in my code that reruns something from the top of the page? - ps. and could you post your suggestion as an answer.. comments not the best way to talk about this :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is not the best answer, just a development from the comments above. I'll try and write a better answer tomorrow.

However, for the time being, my quick workaround would be:

1. Remove, as you mention, the `doSearch` from the top of the page, and set all the initial numbers to 0.
2. Replace your jQuery with this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    $('button#moreResults').click(addResults);

    function addResults(){
        var self = $(this);
        var closestDiv = self.closest('#moreResultsButton');
        var search = closestDiv.find('[id^="search"]').val();
        var count = self.val();
        var countNew = + count + 10;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'../scripts/moreresults.php',
            data:"countNew="+countNew+"&search="+search,
            success:function(){
                var showResult = self.closest('#showResultsAll').find('[id^="showResults"]');
                showResult.load(location.href + " #showResults>*", "");
            }
        });
    }
    
    // load the first ten results
    addResults();
});
```

Please note I did minimal changes to your Javascript. This is not necessarily the most optimal way to do it; I'll revise and edit it tomorrow.

---

Edit: major refactoring

1. `doSearch` is a PHP function that prints the search results to screen. I would change this into a function that returns an array of results. I don't have your code on this, and I don't know how it looks, but it should return something similar to:
   array(
     array( 'name' => 'One', 'surname' => 'Smith' ),
     array( 'name' => 'Two', 'surname' => 'Smythe' ),
     ....
   )
2. `moreresults.php` is the PHP that is called to load new results. Since all the rest of the logic will be done in Javascript, this is for now the ONLY PHP code we call. I would include doSearch() in this file now.

   session_start ();

   require ( "../scripts/functions.php" );

   function doSearch( $pdo, $search, $limit) {
     /* do logic here */
     return $array_of_results;
   }

   // Set variable
   $search = $_POST['search'];
   $limit = $_POST['countNew'];

   $results = doSearch ( $pdo , $search , $limit );

   header('Content-Type: application/json'); // This will tell the client the type of content returned.
   echo json_encode($results); // It is a good idea to make all data transmissions between your server-side code (PHP) and your front-end code (Javascript) in JSON. It's also a good idea to never output anything in your PHP code until the very end, where you have all the required data. It makes it easier to debug later on.
3. Now, the HTML. It doesn't need any PHP preprocessing now, since it will always start the same. We also don't need the tracking of the variables here, since all the logic would be in the Javascript part now.

```html
.
.
.
<div id="showResultsAll">
    .
    .
    .
    <ul id="showResults">
    </ul>
    <button id="loadMore">Load more results</button>
</div>
.
.
.
```

4. The Javascript now bears the weight of most of the logic.

```js
$(function() { // Shorthand for "$(document).ready(function()..."
    var count = 0;
    $("#loadMore").click(loadMoreResults);
    
    function loadMoreResults() {
       var url = "../scripts/moreresults.php";
       var search = $("#search").val();
       count += 10;
       var data = {
          'countNew': count,
          'search': search
       };
       $.post(url, data, showResults, 'json' );
    }
    
    function showResults(data) {
        $("#showResults").empty().append(`
        <li>${data.name} ${data.surname}</li>
        `);
    }
});
```

Notes:

- Since I didn't know what kind of data you're working with, I used a list of names and surnames as an example.
- Likewise, I presented the results as a unordered list () and list items(

  ); you might prefer a table, or something different.

  The code is completely untested. I tried to be careful, but I may have made some typos or other mistakes.

  If I were you, I would try to start by learning some jQuery basics before launching myself into Ajax. The FreeCodeCamp has a nice jQuery course.

  Code architecture is extremely important, and not often well explained in online courses. As a summary:

1. Always plan ahead your code. Pick up a pen&paper, or your favourite text editor, and answer yourself the question: "What must the code do?". Then decompose the answer in smaller steps. Then separate each step into smaller steps, and so on.
2. Whenever you have a piece of code you might need twice, wrap it into a function. Think of functions as small "tasks"
3. Separate as much as possible the logic from the presentation. You should have part of your code working on the data itself, and part of it working on showing the data, and they should be almost independent from each other. You might want to look at the MVC pattern (Model-View-Controller); it may be in process of replacing, but it is a good starting point. This, by the way, is valid both on the backend (doSearch would be the logic, moreresults the presentation) and the frontend (html is the presentation, javascript the logic).

To finish, the code I gave you is not perfect, but I think is a better start. You'll assuredly find many ways to improve it

Comment: Thank you so, so much... I really appreciate this - you taking the time... It 'worked' as in the show more button now does what it is supposed to do... so I will give this an upvote but temporarily hold the checkmark for the better answer tomorrow... 2 weeks ago I didn't know jQuery from a Jack in the Box... and the only way I learn is to be proven wrong... I don't wanna be right - I wanna be better.... so like I said - this is very much appreciated...

Comment: ok... spoke a little too soon... it works the first time... so I search and it shows the first 10 results... then I click the button and it shows 20 results... then I click the button again and nothing happans... I refresh whole page and it shows the 20 results... I click button and it now shows 30 results... I click the button and nothing happens... and on it goes... + if I now click on another page and come back to the search page nothing is shown and button does nothing... now even refresh whole page doesn't work any more... only thing that now works is search again or <shift>+refresh...

Comment: plus the var self = $(this); - line now shows as a strict violation in the code...

Comment: I added a huge expansion to the answer. I hope it helps. Otherwise, you might want to contact me via Skype so we can work on the actual code together.

Comment: Thank you so very much... now it's a lot to unpack hehe - but I will go through it... try out what you suggest... and if I can get it to work I will give you the checkmark for answered :)...

Comment: Ok so I tried your code as is and with a few modifications, but couldn't get it to work - but you made some great points on your written deconstruction of the code that got me on the track to a solution (although I'm still not quite sure why my original code would rerun the doSearch on top of the page, and even though that might be mute now I'm still curious), but my solution that works came from your suggestion to look into MVC and splitting things up in distinct areas of expertice if you will so for that thank you and for that you get to keep your upvote :) for my solution see update...